# How to apply HostOptions.ShutdownTimeout when configuring .NET Core Generic Host?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using the .NET Core Generic Host (not Web Host) to build a Console app that needs a rather lengthy graceful shutdown.  From the source code in

`aspnet/Hosting/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostOptions`

it seems pretty clear that the `ShutdownTimeout` option can be used to change the shutdown timeout in the cancellation token that is provided as a parameter to `ShutdownAsync`.  By default it is 5 seconds.

However, I can't figure out where and how to write the code to specify this option in the `HostBuilder` configuration code that you typically put in the `Program.cs` file.

Can someone post some code that shows how to do this?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core? If so, please edit your question and add the `asp.net-core` tag to it, so that is easier for users to find it. Also, if that's the case, maybe you're looking for the [UseShutdownTimeout()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.useshutdowntimeout) extension method, which you can call in your web host builder object to configure a TimeSpan for the shutdown time.

Comment: No, I am using the Generic Host.  I updated the question to make that clearer.  The `HostOptions` class defines a property `public TimeSpan ShutdownTimeout { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);`, but it is not clear to me how to apply it in the `HostBuilder` configuration.

Comment: I should further clarify that I am using .NET Core 2.1.1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out ...  Here's an outline the configuration code in my Program.cs Main function, with most of the items elided, to show where the configuration for HostOptins.ShutdownTimeout goes.

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost => {...})
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) => {...})
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
           services.AddHostedService<ApplicationLifetime>();          
           ...
           services.Configure<HostOptions>(
                opts => opts.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(...)
        .UseConsoleLifetime()
        .Build();

    try
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException)
    {
        ; // suppress
    }
}
```

To make the this work, here is the StopAsync method in my IHostedService class:

```cs
public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("TaskCanceledException in StopAsync");
        // do not rethrow
    }
}
```

See [Graceful shutdown with Generic Host in .NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044781/graceful-shutdown-with-generic-host-in-net-core-2-1) for more details about this.

Btw, the catch block in `Program.Main` is necessary to avoid an unhandled exception, even though I am catching the exception generated by awaiting the cancellation token in `StopAsync`; because it seems that an unhandled `OperationCanceledException` is also generated at expiration of the shutdown timeout by the framework-internal version of `StopAsync`.

Comment: I may be wrong or it may not have been previously possible but why not just use `services.Configure<HostOptions>(x => x.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))`?

Answer (score 5):

### A relevant answer for ASP.NET Core 6+:

#### Solution 1:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//...
builder.WebHost.UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
//...
var app = builder.Build();
```

#### Solution 2:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//...
builder.Services.Configure<HostOptions>(
     opts => opts.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
//...
var app = builder.Build();
```

#### Solution 3:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//...
builder.Services.PostConfigureAll<HostOptions>(opts => 
    opts.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
//...
var app = builder.Build();
```

Solution 3 will be applied after all others.