# Kubectl apply interactively .NET Core console app with a Console.ReadLine exits on Kubernetes

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run a `.NET Core` console app on `Kubernetes` which should be kept alive with a `Console.ReadLine`.

`Docker` image is being run with a `kubectl apply -f ....yaml` command. Is there a way to run this command sort of interactively, forcing it now to close?

I did not find anything useful with the `kubectl apply --help` command.

If there is no way of doing this, what would be the best alternative? Running a CMD on the deployment `yaml`? I would rather not do an infite loop. There must be a better solution

Not that I am very proud of the `Console.WriteLine` way of doing it..

UPDATE:

Until I find a better solution, I implemented the following solution

[Does it make sense to run a c# worker service in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996235/does-it-make-sense-to-run-a-c-sharp-worker-service-in-docker)

which is an infinite loop. Tested it and works on `Kubernetes`.

Comment: You can't usually interact with the standard input stream of a Kubernetes pod.  What does "keep alive" mean here; why does the process exit, and why don't you want it to?

Comment: it is just an email microservice listening to Redis for incoming messages to be sent out

Comment: The reason why it has to run continiously is because it uses Redis PubSub to listen to incoming messages and the code exits as soon as it finished running. This app only connects to redis and subscribes to a specific channel and this would not take more than a second probably, meaning it exits straight after that

Comment: It seems like your application code needs to sit in a loop receiving messages: if it sends a Redis `SUBSCRIBE` command and then immediately exits (or sits, waiting for user input, without contacting Redis) then you'll never receive a message.  You might try ensuring this setup works with a local consumer, producer, and Redis (no Kubernetes, possibly no containers at all) before packaging it up.

Comment: I have tested it without Docker and Kubernetes. It works perfectly. The console app has a Console.WriteLine as the last line of code, preveting it from exiting, but in Kubernetes, it just ignores this line and exits anyway.

Comment: If the last thing the program does is wait for the user to press a key, it is not receiving messages from Redis.  I'd focus on fixing that over making the process "not exit".

Comment: David I am not sure in this case which thread does what, but this solution has been tested and worked (running for hours and sending out emails as soon as it came through redis).

Comment: I think this depends on your c# version. This is very easy to create a daemon process that stays alive in dotnet core (non-OS specific), and pre-core, you would design this as a Windows Service instead of a command line utility.

Comment: @Sugafree How did you solve this? Having same issue.