# How to make correctly endless console app .NET Core 3.1 for Ubuntu running on systemd

Tags: c#, .net-core

What is the best practices to make endless console app .NET Core 3.1 for Ubuntu running as a service on systemd?

First I tried:

```
static void Main()
{
   //timers (System.Timers.Timer) initialization for background tasks

   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

and it can't work as a service on systemd because of:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected.

then I tried to change `Console.ReadKey()` to `while(true) {}` but it makes 100% CPU usage.

Comment: First question: what would make your application exit? Would it exit if sent a signal like SIGTERM? If so, 1) Create a new ManualResetEvent (or similar), 2) Subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` and use it to set the event, 3) Have your `Main` method call `manualResetEvent.WaitOne()`

Comment: If this is supposed to be an automatic background service when why are you calling ReadKey? It won't be able to accept user input.

Comment: Anyway... https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-run-a-dotnet-core-console-app-as-a-service-using-systemd-on-linux . If you google ".net core service daemon ubuntu" you'll get other useful-looking results too.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) is the recommended way

Answer (score 6):

What you want is already available through the [Worker Service template](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnet-new-worker-windows-services-or-linux-systemd-services-in-net-core). This template creates console applications that can then be hosted as either Windows or Linux services.

Worker services are described in [Steve Gordon's What are .NET Worker Services?](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/what-are-dotnet-worker-services). Systemd hosting is explained in in Scott Hanselman's [dotnet new worker - Windows Services or Linux systemd services in .NET Core](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnet-new-worker-windows-services-or-linux-systemd-services-in-net-core). These two articles are a *lot* cleaner and easier to understand than [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). Start from these two before reading up on BackgroundService.

**Worker class**

A worker service is a class that implements the `IHostedService` interface and lives as long as the `Host` of an application lives. Typically, this is done through the `BackgroundService` base class which implements the `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` methods so a worker only needs to implement `ExecuteAsync` :

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

When termination is signaled either through the console or a system message/signal, the Host notifies the service to exit gracefully before it's forcefully shut down.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

This host is the same one used by ASP.NET Core services, which means one can configure dependency injection, logging, configuration etc

**Console Lifecycle**

[RunConsoleAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#runconsoleasync) can be used instead of `RunAsync()` to allow the application to shutdown on Ctrl+C (on Windows) or SIGINT/SIGTERM (on Linux)

**Hosting**

The [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsService](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-and-systemd/?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) packages take care of setting up the console application to run as either a Windows or systemd service.

To either hosting method, all that's needed is a call to the proper function:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

or

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSystemd()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

Comment: To add to this answer (that I upvoted), see my answer here ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996235/does-it-make-sense-to-run-a-c-sharp-worker-service-in-docker/62996877#62996877

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `Main` method to exit when your process is sent a signal sugh as SIGTERM (which systemd will use to terminate your process, by default). In that case, you don't want to block `Main` forever: you just want to block it until your app receives SIGTERM.

One easy way to do this is using a `ManualResetEvent` and [the `AppDomain.CurrentProcess.ProcessExit` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291567/killing-gracefully-a-net-core-daemon-running-on-linux):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: false);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (o, e) => exitEvent.Set();

    // Set up timers, etc

    exitEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

If you want better integration with systemd, consider using [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd). This is more of a managed solution using a bunch of other hosting infrastructure, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) for the top-level details, and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-and-systemd/) for using it with systemd specifically.