# Automating REST API data to csv with C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, scheduled-tasks

I have data that I'm bringing back from an API using the GET call.  I'm storing this to .csv, however new to both C# and Visual Studio packages.  The data will update overnight therefore I need this package to run daily.  What I'm trying to ask is via SQL server I would normally add the Stored Procedure to a SQL job and setup a scheduler.  What is the best practice on automated C# scripts?  Is Windows Task Scheduler the best option? or is there a preferred solution to this?

Comment: You should clarify whether you are using dotnetCORE or dotnetFRAMEWORK.  Answers can vary slightly.  And if you are "deploying" to a cloud environment or on premise.

Comment: Yes, windows task scheduler is a good choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from source to sql server.

(One way) (C# "centric")

In the DotNetCore world.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

In ASP.NET Core, background tasks can be implemented as hosted services. A hosted service is a class with background task logic that implements the IHostedService interface. This topic provides three hosted service examples:

**Background task that runs on a timer.**
Hosted service that activates a scoped service. The scoped service can use dependency injection (DI).
Queued background tasks that run sequentially.

This would be the code that reads your source-data "CSV", and sends the data to Sql Server.

There are already several "read csv" nuget libraries available.

For example:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

=========

(Another way) (Sql Server "centric")

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-import-export-csv-files-with-r-in-sql-server-2016/

============

Then you create a "WebApi" project that will read from SqlServer......and server up the data.

========

On the "hosted service", there is more info here: [Does it make sense to run a c# worker service in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996235/does-it-make-sense-to-run-a-c-sharp-worker-service-in-docker/62996877#62996877)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [heartbeat](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/Heartbeat/-/php-heartbeat-class-examples.html) task for this. In general, you will need a heartbeat manager, that is a class that has an infinite loop, with a sleep scheduled for a while, so it will not eat up your resources.

## Sleep

You will need a

```
while (true) {
    //Perform the tasks
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //Sleeps for a second
}
```

In your heartbeat manager.

## Heartbeat interface

It's advisable to create an `interface` for your heartbeat tasks, which has an `IsActive` boolean method a `Run` and a `Join`. All your tasks (initially you will have a single task, but this approach supports multiple tasks) will need to implement this interface.

## Managing the tasks

In your infinite cycle you will need an `IEnumerable` of `IHeartbeat` (or whatever name you give the `interface`) element and loop the elements of the `IEnumerable`, like this:

```
while (true) {
    for (IHeartbeat hb in myHeartbeats) {
        if (hb.IsActive()) hb.Run();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

## Synchronizing

You may want to synchronize your jobs. The best way to do that is to initialize an empty `List` as the first step of your `while`, in your `foreach` loop add every `hb` whose `IsActive` was `true` to the `List` and after the `foreach` loop have another `foreach` loop where you call `hb.Join()`.

## Implementation of a hearbeat task

You need to implement `IHeartbeat` to ensure consistency and under the hood you will need to create a `Thread` for the job that's started, so the job will work and you could `Join` it when needed.

## IsActive

Checks whether the current time fulfills the criteria for the job to be run (whether we are at the right time).

## Run

Creates a `Thread` and uses it in order to execute the job's bulk.

## Join

Calls `myThread.Join()`.

## Timing

For the sake of simplicity, the sleep gets 1000 milliseconds, or, in simpler terms a second in this case, but you may want to enhance this a bit according to your needs.